# One-line if-else in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a one-line implementation of the following simple piece of logic ?

```
if (a != null) 
{
    b = a ;
}
else
{
    // do something else;
}
```

Notice that in the `else` I do not want to assign a different value to the variable b.

Comment: You can do: `if (a != null) b = a;` all in one line

Comment: ternary operator

Comment: b = a != null ? a : b

Comment: If you need the `else` block, which doesn't assign to `b`, then no.

Comment: lines-- sometimes means readability--, what's wrong with multiple lines?

Comment: a = a ? null : b = a;

Comment: @L_Oste_Fa_No it depends a lot on what you do or dont want in the else, if you dont want anything JayV's answer was spot on.. if you want something else, you can do it in one line.. but as others have said it doesnt gain anything in one line

Comment: @BugFinder ok, I understand. Let's say in the ``else`` I simply need to set a flag to false. Perhaps there is not so much to be gained, but I thought there was a more efficient way to do this. It is relevant to me because this kind of checks appear very often in my code.

Comment: @L_Oste_Fa_No Define "efficient"

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "a more efficient way of doing this"? Having looked at the answers given - there are ways of doing it all on one line - but they are more complex to understand & probably produce more code. Sometimes simple is good. As far as doing everything all on one line is concerned - it makes debugging a nightmare - in C# Visual Studio it is possible to set breakpoints within one line - but it is a real pain (other languages like C++ do not have this facility at least to VS2015).

Comment: In this case by efficient I mean that one could obtain the same logic without repeating ``a`` . But I guess you are right saying that in order to do this the code complexity increases significantly and at the end it is probably better to keep it simple.

Comment: @L_Oste_Fa_No Exactly, if you had to read someone else's code, would you prefer the code in your question or in the accepted answer?

Comment: @vc74 I guess you know the answer ;-) It seems like I will keep the code the way it was.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody used `b = a ?? b;`. If a is not null it assings it to b and if it's null it assings b to b thus not changing the value of b. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why one would want to do this, but here is my take:

```
((a != null) ? (Action)(() => { b = a; }) : () => { /*Do something else*/ })();
```

Answer (score 26):

Easiest way is probably to do this:

```
b = a != null ? a : b;
```

Syntax for this is:

```
someValue = condition ? newValue : someOtherValue;
```

If you need it to something more specific when a is null then you can do this, but it's not pretty:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int? a = null;
    int b = 0;
    b = a != null ? a.Value : yeet(b);
    
    System.Console.WriteLine(b);
    
}

public static int yeet(int b){
    System.Console.WriteLine("yeet");
    return b;
}
```

Comment: In my mind this would be easier to read with parens around the condition:
`b = (a != null) ? a : b;`

This avoids confusion where it looks like you are assigning to a in the first few characters of the answer.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to do an `if / else` in a single line, you must know the structure that the code must have:

condition ? consequent : alternative

For example:

```
string A = "test";
Console.WriteLine(String.IsNullOrEmpty(A) ? "Yes" : "No");
//Result = No

string B = "";
Console.WriteLine(String.IsNullOrEmpty(B) ? "Yes" : "No");
//Result = Yes
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you were looking for braceless notation?

```
if (a != null) b = a; else /*Do something else*/ ;
```

Please, use this sparingly and make sure the `oneliner` will be readable.

Comment: Well ok :-), but can one avoid repeating the ``a`` ?

Comment: You could easily create a method like `bool SetIfNotNull(object a, object b)` then call it `if(!SetIfNotNull(a,b)) /* Do Something else */`

Comment: @L_Oste_Fa_No, that seems like an interesting puzzle, but I don't think there's any good practical reason in doing so. Definetely would love to see an *elegant* solution though.

Comment: @Seva why sparingly? Is there an issue with this notation?

Comment: I'd say it tends to make the conditional block less readable, especially if the predicate is longer, or an expression in an `if` or `else` branch is longer (character-wise).
If we take some silly example like:
`if (oldUserName != newUserName) user.Name = newUserName; else Console.WriteLine("Not updating user name.");`. I find I need slightly more time to comprehend
this line, rather than having an `if`, the `if` block, `else` and `else` block all on separate lines. Just a question of good formatting for me and tends to eliminate "surprises"
because you missed something in a long line.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't really know why, but yes you can:

```
if (a != null) { b = a; } else { Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the 'else' branch"); }
```

Comment: @GiladGreen Why not?

Comment: @Rafalon because under this logic the entire C# program can be a one-liner :)

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this answer and properly format it ;)

Comment: @GiladGreen Yes, it does.  If you want something other than not having new line characters, then you should ask for *that*, not to have the code without any new line characters.

Comment: @vc74 Me too :-)

Comment: If that bothers you, you could even remove brackets `if(a!=null) b=a; else Console.WriteLine("Blabla");`

Answer (score 0):

```
string asd = "asd";
string bsd = null;

asd = bsd != null ? bsd : new Func<string>(() => { Console.WriteLine("Do something"); return asd; })();
```

This won't change asd and it is "one-liner" but i would not recommend this over normal if else